# How can I have Subversion keep only the latest version of a file?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a large file in my repository that is not text-mergeable and that I do not need multiple-version control for (PPT for example).  I would like to keep it on the repository for backup purposes and to share with multiple people, but I do not want the repository size to grow huge because it's keeping a duplicate copy of the file every time it changes.  Is there a way to specify this behavior for a file in a Subversion repository?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like just to say that I think this is a more worthwhile question than many commenters seem to indicate. Sure, the purpose of Subversion is not to feel only the latest version of a file - but there is something to be said for consistency...

Comment: ...The submitter said they want to keep the files alongside other, versioned, files. I can also imagine a hybrid case where you wouldn't mind having a limited history, but have an auto-purge option after so many revisions, or by storage threshold. This could be useful

Comment: I wonder if, as an alternative, there is a method to use some svn hooks you could use to automatically retrieve a file from another location on checkout/update?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone.  This is indeed meant to be held in a repository along with other version controlled files, but some files are simply so huge that it's not economical to backup every version. But it seems that for many file types binary diffs should save much of the overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible in Subversion. However: subversion keeps the changes to this file as binary diffs in the repository, so depending on the type of changes you make it won't consume a lot of extra space.

Comment: +1 In other words, only the changes to a file are added when it's versioned, not a full copy of the file in its new state.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Subversion is designed to keep the different versions of files. It's a version control system, after all.

Maybe just don't put it in subversion, but back it up or share it using [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - and rightly so.

If a file doesn't change then only one version is stored. If a file does change then surely the point of using version control of any form is so that you can retrieve and earlier version. It may seem now that you would never want to do this, but the chances are that at some point in the future you will want to retrieve it.

If space is a problem get a bigger disk or upgrade your plan. It will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: I don't totally agree. I have a different, but somewhat comparable arrangement at home where I have iMovie files backed up by Time Machine. Any time I do an edit to an iMovie file the whole thing gets duplicated - and each file is about 5-10 GB! My backup disks fill up pretty quickly

Comment: That's not really the same situation because when using version control you commit your changes when they are finished. Versioning large (media) files is almost a separate discipline and I'm not sure that I'd use subversion for it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative may be to store a symlink, then host the file on a network share.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm saying it, but MS Visual Source Safe has this functionality. However, I would not recommend using MS-VSS it due to too many reasons. Main two are instability issues and since it is virtually impossible to use branching (officially this option exists, but practically, it does not work well).

Comment: The original question was about Subversion.